# SAS (University Edition), Proc SQL error involving where statement in create table

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

So, I've listed below the code that I was inputting and the error that I was receiving. I've done this below on the normal SAS on the computers at school, but now I'm using a laptop and using SAS University Edition. I ran my data through PROC GLMSELECT, for the fact that it partitions into TEST, TRAIN, VALIDATE. Now I'm trying to take out every row that has TRAIN in the *ROLE* column and make a new data out of it, same for TEST and VALIDATE also.

```
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 55         
 56         Proc SQL;
 57         Create table Train122004 as
 58         Select *
 59         From PF122004
 60         Where _Role_ = Train
 61         ;
 ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributin tables: Train.
 NOTE: PROC SQL set option NOEXEC and will continue to check the syntax of statements.
 62         
 63         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 75
```

I can give whatever more anyone needs to help with this. I can give a sample of what the data looks like, the reason why I'm doing this, anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Train` is a value in the column, not a column name. Therefore, it should be surrounded by quotes (`'`):

```
 57         Create table Train122004 as
 58         Select *
 59         From PF122004
 60         Where _Role_ = 'Train'
 61         ;
```

Comment: Geez, I see the mistake now! When I moved from my previous SAS file I just replaced the whole thing and forgot to add the quotes back! Thank you so much!